# Zf2 Set new config values

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-config

I am looking for a possibility to override existing configuration values with new ones during runtime.

So sth. like that would be nice:

```
$this->serviceLocator->set('Config', $this->config);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, you can do that. Whether you should do that is an entire matter altogether. So:

```
$this->serviceLocator->setAllowOverride(true); 
// service keys are case insensitive
// just remember that $this->config should contain the whole config
$this->serviceLocator->setService('Config', $this->config);
$this->serviceLocator->setAllowOverride(false);
```

For `setService` to work you need to toggle a flag called `allowOverride`. You can see that [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L393). Afterwards you should probably disable overrides, hence another call to `setAllowOverride`.

Also: [you can hook into `EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG` and change it there](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#manipulating-merged-configuration).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It is unfortunate that I have had to add to config at runtime, but the alternative was overriding a tonne of zend classes which is always a pain :)

Answer (score 0):

Existing config values can simply be overridden by custom setting them inside the `config.php` file in the config folder of your modules. You don't need to do this using the `ServiceLocator`. The array in this file is a global array. The keys in the array will be overwritten in the order that you are loading your modules.

Comment: I know that. I want to override the config for example in the onBootstrap-function of module.php

Comment: @user3314010 Maybe you can explain what you want to achieve? I think config should be static. If you make config dynamic you can end up in trouble. You can load/set custom config for certain services inside your factories.

Comment: Have found a solution which works for me: $serviceLocator->setAllowOverride(true);
                    $serviceLocator->setService('config', $configuration);
                    $serviceLocator->setAllowOverride(false);